# Magento 2,How to add google reCaptcha on the PayPal Payflow payment method in checkout page

Tags: magento2, paypal, captcha

I want to add Google reCaptcha on the Checkout page. Is there any way to add google reCaptcha on PayPal payment method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the Google reCaptcha on the Checkout page.[This link](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025515991) is useful for me for that

Comment: Bro, is Captcha available for PayPal Payments Pro?

Comment: Kindly tell about about is Captcha available for PayPal Payments Pro

Comment: No. It's just for Paypal Payflow Payment method

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok, I understood. Anything else same like for PayPal Payments Pro?

Comment: can You please share about anything else same like for PayPal Payments Pro?

Comment: @ARUNPRABAKARANM, I have Not an idea about that